# Can I return the values of multiple documents' fields in a Solr query?

Tags: java, lucene, solr, subquery

Suppose I have these fields in a document schema:

```
<field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
<field name="type" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
<field name="referenceDataValues" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
<field name="text" type="text" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true" />
```

Document A has these values for the listed fields:

- id: "do not care"
- type: "SalesOrder"
- referenceDataValues: ["abcdefg" , "hijklmn", "opqrst"]
- text: ["do", "not", "care", "either"]

Document B has these values:

- id: "do not care"
- type: "SalesOrder"
- referenceDataValues: ["hijklmn", "opqrst"]
- text: ["red", "paint"]

Document C has these values:

- id: "abcdef"
- type: "Customer"
- referenceDataValues: (null)
- text: ["hello", "world", "how", "ya", "doing"]

Document D has these values:

- id: "hijklmn"
- type: "Customer"
- referenceDataValues: (null)
- text: ["hello", "world", "how", "ya", "doing"]

Default search is only on the text field.

If a user enters the query, "SalesOrder red paint Customer hello world", I want to construct a Solr query that returns only Document B. Meaning, get me the (SalesOrders whose text has red OR paint) who reference Customers whose text has hello OR world

The algorithm for reaching this would be like so:

First, the results of this query:

q="hello world"&fq=type:Customer&fl=id

which would be documents C and D, containing only the IDs. However, I want to actually get these **values** in each of the id fields, not the documents,  so I can see if they exist in the referenceDataValues fields in the SalesOrders documents.

q="red paint"&fq=type:SalesOrder&fq=referenceDataValues:(nest here the id values from the previous query)

Is it possible to return the values of the ID fields in the first query? If yes, what would the syntax look like for this nested query?

Right now, the query I am attempting to use looks like this:

```
q=red paint&start=0&rows=25&fq=type:SalesOrder&fq=referenceDataValues:(_query_:"{!lucene fq=type:CustomerPartyMaster&fl=id} hello world")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is a kind of join on the ids. The id of Document C and D is as a foreign key in the reference data values for Document A and B

You may want to check the join patch - 
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-2272

If it doesn't work, you may end up indexing the documents and their reference data as a single entity, so that you can search across and filter accordingly.

Comment: From my research, the join patch is the closest to doing what I want in one query. However, I'm using Solr 1.x and the patch will be ready for 4.0. In the meantime, I've constructed my own join out of multiple queries and performance is good.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [FieldList parameter](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#fl) ??

You can specify which fields your query should return and then just do the second query where you filter by referenceDataValues:returnedID

But you need to test how it works (i am thinking about performance) when the result of the first query contains lots of IDs.

Comment: That's what I essentially am trying to do. However, is it possible to get this result in one query? Where you have "referenceDataValues:returnedID", I want to embed a query returning one or more id values in place of "returnedID". But I'm not sure the nested query can actually return the string(s) from the id field (the query always returns the documents themselves, right?).

Comment: So, by embedding this query within another: q="hello world"&fq=type:Customer&fl=id , I am hoping a bunch of id strings are returned, not a bunch of documents. Then the surrounding query filters on referenceDataValues using those ids.

Comment: I understand. I don't know if it is possible to do it in one query. The suggestion offered by Jatendra Patil looks like would solve your problem from one query. Using my approach you need to do 2 queries. If you use **fl=id** in your query it will only return one field in the document.